# Eclipse problem when i tried to run a GAE project

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

When i want to run the GAE app, eclipse throw the following warnings:

> 26/01/2011 18:14:07
> org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry
> registerExtensions
>
> Warning: Extension
> Point
> "org.eclipse.core.resources.natures"
> not registered, but plugin
> "org.eclipse.jdt.core" defined in
> file:/C:/------/workspaceAppEngine/----/war/WEB-INF/lib/core-3.1.1.jar
> refers to it.
>
> 26/01/2011 18:14:07
> org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry
> registerExtensions Warning: Extension
> Point
> "org.eclipse.core.resources.builders"
> not registered, but plugin
> "org.eclipse.jdt.core" defined in
> file:/C:/----/workspaceAppEngine/-----/war/WEB-INF/lib/core-3.1.1.jar
> refers to it.
>
> 26/01/2011 18:14:07
> org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry
> registerExtensions Warning: Extension
> Point
> "org.eclipse.core.resources.markers"
> not registered, but plugin
> "org.eclipse.jdt.core" defined in
> file:/C:/----------/workspaceAppEngine/-----/war/WEB-INF/lib/core-3.1.1.jar
> refers to it.
>
> 26/01/2011 18:14:07
> org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry
> registerExtensions Warning: Extension
> Point
> "org.eclipse.core.resources.markers"
> not registered, but plugin
> "org.eclipse.jdt.core" defined in
> file:/C:/-----/workspaceAppEngine/----/war/WEB-INF/lib/core-3.1.1.jar
> refers to it.

any idea?

Thanks

Comment: so it enhanced with success, and you're not running in Eclipse RCP. ok

Comment: Does the app run? These warnings look non-critical to me.

Comment: The application runs, but the part that has to communicate with the storage does not work. (I'm using JPA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error, using Objectify instead of JPA. More info: http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using version 2.0.0.m3? Check [this](http://www.jpox.org/servlet/jira/browse/NUCCORE-380?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel).

Comment: I'm using this version of datanucleus: DataNucleus Enhancer (version 1.1.4) : Enhancement of classes
DataNucleus Enhancer completed with success for 1 classes. Timings : input=327 ms, enhance=75 ms, total=402 ms. Consult the log for full details